# How can I make data "messy"?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset of 2 variables ("param1", "param2") measured in duplicates for 3 experimental conditions (3 treatments "tx1", "tx2", "tx3").  The output from the instrument looks like this:

```
 # A tibble: 6 x 3
  treatment param1 param2
  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>
1 tx1           20    300
2 tx1           22    310
3 tx2          155    400
4 tx2          160    403
5 tx3           34    900
6 tx3           40    890
```

where duplicates are below each other. I am using GraphPad Prism for creating graphs, which requires duplicates next to each other, like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  treatment param1.1 param1.2 param2.1 param2.2
  <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 tx1             20       22      300      310
2 tx2            155      160      400      401
3 tx3             34       40      900      890
```

I know this is not tidy data, but I am stuck with the graphing program until I learn how to use ggplot efficiently.

I guess the answer is in "gather" or "spread", but I don't know how to do it. Please help.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

We can create a unique index for each group and then use `pivot_wider` which now allows to include values from multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 group_by(treatment) %>%
 mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
 tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = c(param1, param2))


#  treatment param1_1 param1_2 param2_1 param2_2
#  <fct>        <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
#1 tx1             20       22      300      310
#2 tx2            155      160      400      403
#3 tx3             34       40      900      890
```

---

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), treatment~rowid(treatment), value.var = c('param1', 'param2'))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("tx1", "tx2", "tx3"), class = "factor"), param1 = c(20L, 
22L, 155L, 160L, 34L, 40L), param2 = c(300L, 310L, 400L, 403L, 
900L, 890L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```